# What car wash tasks should be done after an automatic car wash?

Tags: maintenance

I have access to free automatic car washes. It is a pretty basic and short cloth car wash and dry. What should I do in additional to the automatic car wash? I was thinking about drying off any spots that are not completely dry with a microfiber towel. Should I also ideally put something on say the tires or windshield? More generally, what are automatic car washes poor at and what can be done to make up for these deficiencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drying is the most important part.  Try to dry out all the areas where water can collect and sit.  Same thing if the car is out in the rain.  That sitting water leads to rust.